# Посчитать количество карт которые закончат свое действие в текущем месяце

Tags: sql, oracle

Имеется список транзакций по картам, в каждой транзакции указывается дата окончания действия карты, к примеру:

```
DT          card        DT_OFF
10.10.2019  1244        05.11.2019
11.10.2019  1433        27.10.2019
15.10.2019  1433        27.10.2019
03.11.2019  1244        05.11.2019
04.11.2019  1244        05.11.2019
```

Как сделать группировку по месяцам (**group by to_char(DT,'yyyy.mm')**), что бы узнать сколько карт в месяце перестанут работать.

Comment: Странно... вроде в вопросе практически написан ответ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(dt_off,'yyyy.mm') year_month, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT card) `count`
FROM sourcetable
/* если надо не по всем возможным, а за некий период, то */
/*     WHERE dt_off BETWEEN @date_start AND date_end     */
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(dt_off,'yyyy.mm')
ORDER BY 1
```

Само собой в списке не будет года-месяца, если в нём ни одна карта не оканчивает своё действие.

Если такие годы-месяцы нужны с нулевым количеством - генерируйте список в заданном диапазоне и используйте его как опорный.

Comment: Ну не совсем то что нужно, я же написал, что основной группировкой является DT, а не DT_OFF, там в запросе выводится еще много разных параметров по разным столбцам по месяцам с группировкой по дате транзакции, по этому и надо отталкиваться именно от GROUP BY TO_CHAR(dt,'yyyy.mm')

Comment: @Rulez Дата окончания - это `dt_off`? Значит, для получения количества надо группировать по этому полю, и без вариантов. Или у Вас есть некий супер-запрос, и Вы хотите в него добавить ещё поле, с этим количеством? Надеюсь, не надо объяснять, что даже если получить отдельно показанным подзапросом эти данные, и прилепить их к исходному запросу, данные получатся бредовые, ибо каждой группе с определённым `TO_CHAR(dt,'yyyy.mm')` будут соответствовать несколько кусочков, надёрганных из разных групп `TO_CHAR(dt_off,'yyyy.mm')`?

Comment: Ну вот я тоже сколько не думал, ничего хорошего не придумал.

Comment: @Rulez А что тут думать? две пересекающиеся группировки собрать вменяемо в одном наборе данных невозможно в принципе. Получай эти данные отдельным набором, отдельным запросом. А что с этим потом делать, и к какой заднице прислонить - это уж пусть думает тот, кто вылепил подобное задание.

Answer (score -1):

Можно указать : select count(card) from DATABASENAME where DT_OFF like'%11.2019%' если выборку по ноябрю делать.

Comment: да вот как раз надо не за конкретный месяц, а за каждый

Comment: Я ещё далеко не спец. Сейчас пишу приложение календарь, где при выборе дня вылезают записи сделанные на этот день. В этих записях указаны: менеджер, дата, тип работы, клиент и ещё кое что. + к этому необходима статистика, кто, чего, когда сделал записал. Теперь суть. Возможно, это всё можно упростить - оптимизировать ( но я ещё не знаю как ), так я пишу по каждой позиции запрос, и потом вывожу их все вместе на страницу. Создал страницу статистики, где есть <label for="date"> Выберите месяц: </label><br/>
                <input id="date" type="month" name="date2"/>

Comment: Всё не влезло. Выбираю месяц, жму поиск и вуаля, получаем всё, что запрашиваем. Но, я пишу на фреймворке Spring Boot. Я бы запрашивал каждый месяц отдельно.